# Copy Column name and number in table1 to table2

Tags: javascript, html

Please help required Copy Column name and number in table1 to table2
Copies the Name and Number column into a table2Through JavaScript

From this distinguished forum I learned a lot of information
And my sincere thanks and appreciation
And my sincere thanks and appreciation
And my sincere thanks and appreciation

```html
<html dir="ltr">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-sa">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>copy</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>

function copytable() {

}


</script>

<p align="center">Copy Column name and number <span lang="en-us">in table1 to 
table2</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div align="center">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="75%" dir="rtl" height="201">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%" valign="top">
            <p align="center"><span lang="en-us"><font size="4">&nbsp;id : table 
            2</font></span></p>
            <div align="center">
                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" id="table2" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="197" dir="rtl" bordercolorlight="#000000" bordercolordark="#000000">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" width="83" align="center">
                        number</td>
                        <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="center"><span lang="en-us">
                        name</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="83">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <p>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="20%" valign="top">
            <p align="center"><span lang="en-us"><font size="4">&nbsp;id : table 
            1</font></span></p>
            <div align="center">
                <table border="1" id="table1" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="345" dir="ltr" bordercolorlight="#000000" bordercolordark="#000000">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" height="22" bgcolor="#669999" width="64">
                        <span lang="en-us"><font color="#FFFFFF">name </font>
                        </span></td>
                        <td align="center" height="22" bgcolor="#669999">
                        <span lang="en-us"><font color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;number</font></span></td>
                        <td align="center" height="22" bgcolor="#669999" width="103">
                        <font color="#FFFFFF"><span lang="en-us">email</span></font></td>
                        <td align="center" height="22" bgcolor="#669999" width="71">
                        <font color="#FFFFFF">ZIP code</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="64"><span lang="en-us">jack</span></td>
                        <td align="center"><span lang="en-us">0989</span></td>
                        <td align="center" width="103"><span lang="en-us">
                        <a href="mailto:h@js.com">h@js.com</a></span></td>
                        <td align="center" width="71"><span lang="en-us">4456</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="64">Willem</td>
                        <td align="center">2243</td>
                        <td align="center" width="103"><span lang="en-us">
                        <a href="mailto:cv@ys.com">cv@ys.com</a></span></td>
                        <td align="center" width="71"><span lang="en-us">8892</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="64">George</td>
                        <td align="center">465</td>
                        <td align="center" width="103"><span lang="en-us">
                        <a href="mailto:tr@ts.com">tr@ts.com</a></span></td>
                        <td align="center" width="71"><span lang="en-us">92112</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="64">Sarah</td>
                        <td align="center">7763</td>
                        <td align="center" width="103"><span lang="en-us">
                        <a href="mailto:sa@dss.com">sa@dss.com</a></span></td>
                        <td align="center" width="71"><span lang="en-us">8993</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="40%" valign="top" colspan="2">
            <p align="center">Copy to a table<span lang="en-us">2</span></p>
            <p align="center">
 <input type="button" onclick="copytable()" value="    copy    "></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you need to copy the name and number across all lines, or just one?

Comment: s.kuznetsov  Yes, all the lines

Comment: This can be done using the `forEach()` method or the `for {}` with creatElement. You have tried anything from the javascript logic.

Comment: s.kuznetsov    The important thing is that the code works in a way that I hope for help

Comment: You have tried anything from the javascript logic?

Comment: s.kuznetsov   No, I don't know much  in  javascript

Comment: s.kuznetsov Your task is to correct this defect and thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this code. Modified your HTML slightly.
I have taken source table data using a single array format

```
[...oTable.rows].map(t => [...t.children].reduce(function(obj,d,i){
  obj[i] =  d.innerText;
  return obj;
},{}))
```

After taken the array just remove the 1st object that was the table header using slice(1)

```js
function copytable(){
  var oTable = document.getElementById('table1');
 
let tableData = [...oTable.rows].map(t => [...t.children].reduce(function(obj,d,i){
  obj[i] =  d.innerText;
  return obj;
},{})).slice(1); 


  let trHtml=tableData.map(r=> `<tr><td>${r["0"]}</td> <td>${r["1"]}</td></tr>`).join("");

  $("#table2 tbody").empty();
  $("#table2 tbody").append(trHtml);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p align="center">Copy Column name and number <span lang="en-us">in table1 to 
    table2</span></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <div align="center">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="75%" height="201">
            <tr>
          <td width="20%" valign="top">
            <p align="center"><span lang="en-us"><font size="4">&nbsp;id : table 
            1</font></span></p>
            <div align="center">
              <table border="1" id="table1" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="345" dir="ltr" bordercolorlight="#000000" bordercolordark="#000000">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" height="22" bgcolor="#669999" width="64">
                  <span lang="en-us"><font color="#FFFFFF">name </font>
                  </span></td>
                  <td align="center" height="22" bgcolor="#669999">
                  <span lang="en-us"><font color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;number</font></span></td>
                  <td align="center" height="22" bgcolor="#669999" width="103">
                  <font color="#FFFFFF"><span lang="en-us">email</span></font></td>
                  <td align="center" height="22" bgcolor="#669999" width="71">
                  <font color="#FFFFFF">ZIP code</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" width="64"><span lang="en-us">jack</span></td>
                  <td align="center"><span lang="en-us">0989</span></td>
                  <td align="center" width="103"><span lang="en-us">
                  <a href="mailto:h@js.com">h@js.com</a></span></td>
                  <td align="center" width="71"><span lang="en-us">4456</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" width="64">Willem</td>
                  <td align="center">2243</td>
                  <td align="center" width="103"><span lang="en-us">
                  <a href="mailto:cv@ys.com">cv@ys.com</a></span></td>
                  <td align="center" width="71"><span lang="en-us">8892</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" width="64">George</td>
                  <td align="center">465</td>
                  <td align="center" width="103"><span lang="en-us">
                  <a href="mailto:tr@ts.com">tr@ts.com</a></span></td>
                  <td align="center" width="71"><span lang="en-us">92112</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" width="64">Sarah</td>
                  <td align="center">7763</td>
                  <td align="center" width="103"><span lang="en-us">
                  <a href="mailto:sa@dss.com">sa@dss.com</a></span></td>
                  <td align="center" width="71"><span lang="en-us">8993</span></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
                </td>
                <td width="20%" valign="top">
              <p align="center"><span lang="en-us"><font size="4">&nbsp;id : table 
              2</font></span></p>
              <div align="center">
              

                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" id="table2" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="197" bordercolorlight="#000000" bordercolordark="#000000">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th bgcolor="#C0C0C0" width="83" align="center">Name</th>
                    <th bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="center"><span lang="en-us">Number</span></th>
                  </tr>
                    </thead>               
                  <tbody>               
                  </tbody>                      
                </table>
              </div>
              <p>&nbsp;

          </td>         
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40%" valign="top" colspan="2">
                <p align="center">Copy to a table<span lang="en-us">2</span></p>
                <p align="center">
     <input type="button" onclick="copytable()" value="    copy    "></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```